# error al guardar archivos en el servidor por PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, session, filesize

intento mandar a guardar un archivo desde un formulario pero se queda en blanco no me muestra nada y no guarda el archivo en la ruta ni la información en la base de datos, este es el action, para guardar desde mi formulario, lo que intento es que se guarde el código que se genera y al mismo tiempo el archivo en la ruta junto con toda la información de los campos, podría ayudarme a ver algún problema en este action si lo hay para que me funcione lo estoy probando en local con xampp

```
<?php

//print_r($_SESSION);
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){

    $alphabeth ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ1234567890_-";
    $code = "";
    for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
        $code .= $alphabeth[rand(0,strlen($alphabeth)-1)];
    }

    $f = new FileData();
    $f->code= $code;
    $f->is_public = isset($_POST["is_public"])?1:0;
    $f->folder_id = $_POST["folder_id"]!=""?$_POST["folder_id"]:"NULL";
    $f->user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
    $f->description = $_POST["description"];


    $handle = new Upload($_FILES['filename']);
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        $url="admin/storage/data/".$_SESSION["user_id"];
        $handle->Process($url);
        if($handle->processed){
        $f->filename = $handle->file_dst_name;
        $f->add();
        Core::alert("Agregado exitosamente!");
        //Core::redir("./?view=home");
        }

    }


}


?>
```

Comment: TENGO COMENTADO LA REDIRECCION PERO ESE NO ES EL PROBLEMA, EL PROBLEMA ES QUE NO GUARDA NADA EL ACTION, SALUDOS, LES LEO!

Comment: me parece que la variable $_POST es un array del tipo $_POST['alguna_cosa']

Comment: si se están declarando los $_POST, no comprendo debería cambiarlos dice?

Comment: me refiero a la primera linea "if(!empty($_POST)" es decir falta la descripción del array ejemplo $_POST['id'] o lo que contenga esa variable

Comment: El problema que describes pasa cuando tratas de subir archivos que superan el límite de `upload_max_filesize`, 2 megabytes por defecto. Debes editar `php.ini` para incrementar el valor y, de paso, también el de `post_max_size` que debe ser mayor que el anterior. También te recomiendo leer [Dificultades comunes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

Comment: intento subir solo un archivo txt no pes ni un mb y no me funciona :/